# Can't install GLIBC_2.33 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, glibc

I'm trying to run a program that requires me to use GLIBC_2.33. I tried to update my programs and do sudo apt install GLIBC_2.33 but none of it has worked, I tried seeking for an answer, but I gave up and decided to ask for myself.

Comment: What program are you trying to install??

Comment: Tux Trouble a Friday Night Funkin' (A rhythm game) mod here's the link https://gamebanana.com/mods/286771